# How can I detect when touch is in the children widget in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How I can detect when touch position in a children widget of game grid? When I want call children method mark_label(). Thank you.

```
class GameGrid(GridLayout):

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        #which label is collision  
        print(str(touch.pos))


class StartScreen(Screen):

    level = Level(mode, 1)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.create_level()

    def create_level(self):
        self.ids.game_grid.clear_widgets()

        labels = self.level.get_letters_label()
        for f in range(len(labels)):
            self.ids.game_grid.add_widget(labels[f])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.collide_points()` method to check for collision of the touch with the widget of interest.

## Snippets

class CreateLabel(Label):

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        # TODO
        # call method mark_label()
        if touch.button == "right":
            print("Right mouse clicked on {}".format(self.text))
        elif touch.button == "left":
            print("Left mouse clicked on {}".format(self.text))
        else:
            print(self.id)
        return True
    return super(CreateLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

[Programming Guide » Events and Properties » Dispatching a Property event](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#dispatching-a-property-event)

> If the touch falls inside of our widget, we change the value of
>   pressed to touch.pos and return True, indicating that we have consumed
>   the touch and don’t want it to propagate any further. 
> ...
>  Finally,
>   if the touch falls outside our widget, we call the original event
>   using super(…) and return the result. This allows the touch event
>   propagation to continue as it would normally have occurred.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class CreateLabel(Label):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            if touch.button == "right":
                print("Right mouse clicked on {}".format(self.text))
            elif touch.button == "left":
                print("Left mouse clicked on {}".format(self.text))
            else:
                print(self.id)
            return True
        return super(CreateLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class RootWidget(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.build_board()

    def build_board(self):
        # make 9 label in a grid
        for i in range(0, 9):
            label = CreateLabel(id=str(i), text="Label {}".format(i))
            self.add_widget(label)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CreateLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 1, 0.5  # 50% blue
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    font_size: 30
    on_touch_down: self.on_touch_down

<RootWidget>:
    rows: 3
    cols: 3
    row_force_default: True
    row_default_height: 150
    col_force_default: True
    col_default_width: 150
    padding: [10]
    spacing: [10]
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Clicked on Label 3]
[image: Img02 - Clicked on Label 8]

Comment: So if i want call method in label, for example i want chenge background color all labels wich user toched, i must write on_touch_down methon for all labels in GameGrid ? not only for GameGrid layout ? 
I understand you correctly?